# How to bind a datagrid column programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I must be forgetting something obvious ... I am unable to BIND a DataGridColumn programatically. I have the following code:

```
        var datagrid = new DataGrid();
        datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = "Type,
            Width = new DataGridLength(200),
            FontSize = 12,
            Binding = new Binding("Name") // this line fails to complile
        });
```

I keep getting the following compilation error:

> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'Binding' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have seen many examples online, seem to be doing the same thing ... any ideas?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var datagrid = new DataGrid();
datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "Type,
    Width = new DataGridLength(200),
    FontSize = 12,
    Binding = new Binding("Name")
});
```

In order to use these code, you must use namespace "`System.Windows.Data`".

```
using System.Windows.Data;
```

Comment: Wow ... it really was as simple as that .... I just don't get why the first binding had no errors (only the second one after the NEW) - but adding that solved the problem for sure ...